# Chrome shows black screen when playing video, but performs well when full screen

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, chrome-for-android, video, android-tv

I have a tablet and an Android TV stick. Both are on Android 4.1 JB.

I have an MP4 video file. On my tablet, the MP4 plays well inside the Chrome browser. But on my Android TV stick, it shows a blank black screen! I could only view the video when it's in fullscreen mode.

I suspect that it's the size of the video or the display. Perhaps it was too small to see in normal mode.

Does anybody have a clue how to deal with it?

Comment: What is the resoultion and the format and encoding of the video and the resolution of the tv stick screen?Is it a 4K resolution video format? Try playing another video of same resolution in android tv stick.

Answer (score 2):

If every video behaves this way, it could be a bug in the display driver for your TV stick. When a video plays full-screen, the video decoder writes the decoded video directly into the *framebuffer*, a special part of memory that holds the image being displayed. When a video is played inside another window, it instead uses an *overlay*, which is a way of combining the video output and the rest of the screen.

If playing videos works fullscreen but not inside another window, this could be a symptom of a error in the part of the display driver that handles overlays. You could check with the manufacturer to see if an updated ROM fixes the error.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the resolution you are trying to play is too high to play in normal mode and hence the blank screen.

Anyways rather than using Google Chrome for videos I'd recommend MX Player which is a very capable media player and supports most videos.

Comment: thank you so much for your response!

but I'm actually doing some Android app programming which needs a webview (plus the webchromeclient), thus I have to ensure that the video is working on chrome.......Any work arounds?? thanks!!!